# Fetch json data using angularjs controller

Tags: json, angularjs

In the following code I converted my data into json object using javascript serializer. How can I fetch the json object to my controller named **UserCntrl** using $http.get so that I can use it in ng-repeat later?

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetUserDetails()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserID=id,Username=username,Mail=email from users", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the ul holding ng-repeat

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
           {{item.Username}}
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have to tweak a few things but this should work.  I abstracted your http request to a factory so you can use it with any controller.

```
app(you have to adjust this to your app).factory('userFactory', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.get = function () {
        return $http.get('your_rest_url', {}).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success', resp);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('ERR', err);
        });
    };
});

var UsrCtrl = function ($scope, userFactory) {
    $scope.items = userFactory.get();
};
```